# Call a function on every wordpress pages only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a security function.

I want to call this function in all pages which are created by wordpress back end only.

`(Does not want want to called by all php files)`.

Is there any **hook available**?

Comment: Does your security function output anything?

Comment: No,This will not outoupt but this will redirect.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use in a php file (like header.php or functions.php) like this

```
if(is_page())
{
   // code to execute on all pages
 }
```

Comment: This does not works in functions.php  and header.php is not called in all pages.

Comment: when any page is created in wordpress backend it will be displayed via `page.php` file you can put your function in that file too if you want the file to execute in all pages. you can read about [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Answer (score 0):

You can tie it to the 'wp_head' hook.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head